# Hide the default App Icon and App name from header in Android [Titanium]

Tags: android, ios, android-actionbar, titanium

I am developing an app for both Android and iOS using Titanium. In iOS there is no default header in the app. The app take full screen. But in Android, there is a default app icon [titanium icon] and app name on each screen. I am using another header for my app so it is looking bad with the app.

Can anyone tell me how to hide the default one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its called action bar in android and here are methods for removing them

http://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2014/08/hiding-the-android-actionbar/

Thanks